# How do I generate a mean by year and industry in Stata

Tags: stata, mean

I'm trying to generate in Stata the mean per year (e.g. 2002-2012) for each industry (by 2 digit SIC codes, so c. 50 different industries)

I found how to do it for one year with:

```
by sic_2digit, sort: egen test = mean(oancf_at_rsd10) if fyear == 2004
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this instead of repeating the command 10 times by hand and than adding the values together?

Comment: Why the downvotes? This isn't an outstanding question, but it shows some code and asks how to extend the approach. I don't think it deserves the obloquy of -4 (at the moment of writing). Alternatively, some of the downvoters should give constructive advice to the OP to explain what they think is wrong and how to improve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify more than one variable with `by:`.

```
by sic_2digit fyear, sort: egen test = mean(oancf_at_rsd10)
```

Check out the help for `by:`, which gives the syntax and an example, and also that for `collapse`.